# ExpandableListView for Windows Phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8

In Android there's [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html). Is there an equivalent in Windows Phone 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing. You can create a DataTemplate that contains ExpanderView from Windows Phone Toolkit: https://phone.codeplex.com/ to achieve similar effect.

Comment: I had a feeling an expander control was required. Thanks!